# Insert data specifically to the selected <select> <option>

Tags: php, html

The idea is to insert an img to a specific row on the database based on the selected item on `<option value>`.

The title of the books are outputted to `<option value>`. If the admin selected a title on `<option value>` and uploaded a img, it will be automatically upload the img into the specific book that they selected.

**index.php**

```
<div class="box1">
            <select class="books-title">
            <option selected disabled>-- select book --</option>
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM books";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                    $sqlBook = "SELECT book_id, book_title FROM books";
                    $resultBook = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlBook);
                    while ($rowBook = mysqli_fetch_array($resultBook)) {
                        echo "<option value='". $rowBook['book_title'] ."'>" .$rowBook['book_title'] ."</option>";
                    }              
                    echo "<form action='includes/upload.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                    <input type='file' name='file' class='uploadImg'>
                    <button type='submit' name='submitImg'>UPLOAD</button>";
                    echo "</form>";
            }else {
                echo "There's no Books yet!";
            }
            echo "</select>";
            ?>
        </div>
```

**upload.php**

```
elseif (isset($_POST['submitImg'])) {
        $file = $_FILES['file'];

        $fileName = $FILES['name'];
        $fileTmpName = $FILES['tmp_name'];
        $fileSize = $FILES['size'];
        $fileError = $FILES['error'];
        $fileType = $FILES['type'];

        $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
        $fileActualExt =strtolower(end($fileExt));

        $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');

        if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
            if ($fileError === 0) {
                if ($fileSize < 1000) {
                    $fileNameNew = $bookID['book_id'].".".$fileActualExt;
                    $fileDestination = '../../images/book_image/'.$fileNameNew;
                    move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
                    header("Location: index.php?uploadsucess");
                }else {
                    echo "Your file is too big!";
                }
            }else {
                echo "There was an error uploading your file!";
            }
        }else{
            echo "You cannot upload files of this type!";
        }
    }
```

[Database Structure Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fc9cJ.png)

Comment: Why are you first making the query `SELECT * FROM books` and then a new query `SELECT book_id, book_title FROM books` if the first returned records? Just make one query and use that result.

Comment: Also, what is your actual question here? You've only told us what you want and then posted a bunch of code. You need to explain (in detail) what you're actual issue is.

Comment: You're currently putting the form and the other inputs _inside_ the select-input. That's not how forms work. All inputs/selects must be inside the form.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, so the thing is this is my admin page for an e-library. The webpage is composed of a selection of books title that is listed using <selection> option and a img uploader. The problem is I can't upload a img to the database using the specific book title that they selected on the drop down selection.

Comment: Start with the basics about how forms work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form. When writing HTML, you can't just put elements where ever you want.

Comment: It seems that there's a bunch of imperfections to my code. will look into it. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: In the PHP that processes the upload where is `$bookID['book_id']` coming from?

Comment: Might want to add a `name` attribute to your `<select>`, so you can access its value in PHP after submitting your form

Comment: sorry for the late reply @ProfessorAbronsius that $bookID should handle the `book_id` number from the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you restructure the FORM so that the `select` is a child of the form like this:

```
<div class="box1">
    <form action='includes/upload.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <select name='booktitle' class="books-title">
            <option selected disabled>-- select book --
            <?php
                $sql='SELECT `book_id`, `book_title` FROM `books`';
                $result=$connection->query($sql);
                while($rs=$result->fetch_object())printf('<option value="%s">%s', $rs->book_id, $rs->book_title );
            ?>
        </select>   
        <input type='file' name='file' class='uploadImg' />
        <button type='submit' name='submitImg'>UPLOAD</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Then the PHP - you mentioned the need to `"insert an img to a specific row on the database based on the selected item"` which suggests doing an `update` query using the `book_id` as the key. This is wholly untested btw but should perhaps help a little?

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset(
    $_POST['booktitle'],
    $_FILES['file']
)){
    
    $obj=(object)$_FILES['file'];
    $name=$obj->name;
    $tmp=$obj->tmp_name;
    $size=$obj->size;
    $error=$obj->error;
    $ext=strtolower( pathinfo( $name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );
    $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');
    
    $bid=(int)$_POST['booktitle'];// `book_id` from `select` menu
    
    
    if( is_uploaded_file( $tmp ) && $error==UPLOAD_ERR_OK && in_array( $ext, $allowed ) && $size < 1024 ){
        
        $destination=sprintf( '../../images/book_image/%s.%s', $bid, $name );
        $status=move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $destination );
        
        if( $status ){
            $sql='update `books` set `book_picture`=? where `book_id`=?';
            $stmt=$connection->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bind_param('ss',$destination,$bid);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        
        
        ob_clean();
        exit( header( "Location: index.php?uploadsucess&status=$status" ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Will try this right now and tell the output